# How to properly type a function that changes the values ​of an object

Tags: typescript, types

I don't have much experience in typescript, so sometimes such questions arise. How to properly type a function that adds a postfix to the values ​​of an object const and returns it

```js
export const POSTFIX = '_postfix';

export const WITHOUT_POSTFIX_VALUES = {
  PRODUCT: 'product',
  ORDER: 'order',
  PERSON: 'person',
} as const;

export const addPostfixToValues = (obj: object) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) =>  [k, `${v}${POSTFIX}`]));

export const WITH_POSTFIX = addPostfixToValues(WITHOUT_POSTFIX_VALUES);
```

here is the link to codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/qsoe7

I want to get the same object with readonly fields but with postfixes added.
Thanks in advance for any information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of question has been asked a lot.  The current version of typescript does not understand mapping of string literals, but that feature will be coming soon.

In the meantime, the best you can do is type `WITH_POSTFIX` as an object with the same keys as `WITHOUT_POSTFIX_VALUES` whose values are strings.  That would be:

```
Record<keyof typeof WITHOUT_POSTFIX_VALUES, string>
```